# os.listdir() fails for every directory on UNIX

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu

This is the most strangest error ever - Python os.listdir() fails for every directory:

```
    Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Jan 20 2010, 23:14:04) 
    [GCC 4.2.4 (Ubuntu 4.2.4-1ubuntu3)] on linux2
    Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
    >>> import os
    >>> os.listdir("/")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/'
    >>> os.listdir("/tmp")
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp'
    >>> os.listdir(os.getcwd())
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
    OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/srv'
```

Ubuntu Linux 8.04. This appeared suddennly on functioning server so I suspect file system corruption. But I have recompiled Python interpreter. I have also tested two different interpreter versions.

Here is a strace from a simple script running os.listdir("/tmp"):

```
    strace python test.py 

    execve("/usr/bin/python", ["python", "test.py"], [/* 17 vars */]) = 0
    brk(0)                                  = 0x75b000
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24b35000
    access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24b33000
    access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = 0
    open("/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLY)    = 3
    fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=22, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 22, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7feb24b32000
    close(3)                                = 0
    open("/lib/libncom.so.4.0.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
    read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\20\25\0"..., 832) = 832
    fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=13176, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 2107936, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7feb24716000
    mprotect(0x7feb24719000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
    mmap(0x7feb24918000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7feb24918000
    close(3)                                = 0
    munmap(0x7feb24b32000, 22)              = 0
    open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
    fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=18355, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 18355, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7feb24b2e000
    close(3)                                = 0
    access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/lib/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY)  = 3
    read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260W\0\0"..., 832) = 832
    fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=130224, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 2208624, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7feb244fa000
    mprotect(0x7feb24510000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
    mmap(0x7feb24710000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7feb24710000
    mmap(0x7feb24712000, 13168, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24712000
    close(3)                                = 0
    access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/lib/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY)       = 3
    read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 \16\0\0"..., 832) = 832
    fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14624, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24b2d000
    mmap(NULL, 2109728, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7feb242f6000
    mprotect(0x7feb242f8000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
    mmap(0x7feb244f8000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7feb244f8000
    close(3)                                = 0
    access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/lib/libutil.so.1", O_RDONLY)     = 3
    read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\16\0"..., 832) = 832
    fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=10584, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 2105624, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7feb240f3000
    mprotect(0x7feb240f5000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
    mmap(0x7feb242f4000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0x7feb242f4000
    close(3)                                = 0
    access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/lib/libm.so.6", O_RDONLY)        = 3
    read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260>\0\0"..., 832) = 832
    fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=526560, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 2621672, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7feb23e72000
    mprotect(0x7feb23ef2000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
    mmap(0x7feb240f1000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x7f000) = 0x7feb240f1000
    close(3)                                = 0
    access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY)        = 3
    read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\340\342"..., 832) = 832
    fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1436976, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24b2c000
    mmap(NULL, 3543672, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7feb23b10000
    mprotect(0x7feb23c68000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
    mmap(0x7feb23e68000, 20480, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x158000) = 0x7feb23e68000
    mmap(0x7feb23e6d000, 17016, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb23e6d000
    close(3)                                = 0
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24b2b000
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24b2a000
    arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7feb24b2a6e0) = 0
    mprotect(0x7feb23e68000, 12288, PROT_READ) = 0
    munmap(0x7feb24b2e000, 18355)           = 0
    set_tid_address(0x7feb24b2a770)         = 11879
    set_robust_list(0x7feb24b2a780, 0x18)   = 0
    futex(0x7fff2cb3530c, 0x81 /* FUTEX_??? */, 1) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {0x7feb244ff2d0, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7feb245087d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {0x7feb244ff350, [], SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, 0x7feb245087d0}, NULL, 8) = 0
    rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
    getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
    futex(0x7feb244f910c, 0x81 /* FUTEX_??? */, 2147483647) = 0
    brk(0)                                  = 0x75b000
    brk(0x77c000)                           = 0x77c000
    open("test.py", O_RDONLY)               = 3
    fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30, ...}) = 0
    ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24ae9000
    open("/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY)         = 4
    fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0444, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24b32000
    read(4, "MemTotal:      1692120 kB\nMemFre"..., 1024) = 630
    close(4)                                = 0
    munmap(0x7feb24b32000, 4096)            = 0
    fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
    fstat(0, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
    fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
    fstat(2, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
    stat("/usr/lib/kde4/bin/python", 0x7fff2cb31d70) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/usr/local/sbin/python", 0x7fff2cb31d70) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/usr/local/bin/python", 0x7fff2cb31d70) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/usr/sbin/python", 0x7fff2cb31d70) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/usr/bin/python", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1387928, ...}) = 0
    readlink("/usr/bin/python", "python2.5", 4096) = 9
    readlink("/usr/bin/python2.5", 0x7fff2cb31e00, 4096) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
    stat("/usr/bin/Modules/Setup", 0x7fff2cb31d70) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/usr/bin/lib/python2.5/os.py", 0x7fff2cb31d70) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/usr/bin/lib/python2.5/os.pyc", 0x7fff2cb31d70) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/usr/lib/python2.5/os.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=24624, ...}) = 0
    stat("/usr/bin/Modules/Setup", 0x7fff2cb31d70) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/usr/bin/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload", 0x7fff2cb31d70) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
    brk(0x79e000)                           = 0x79e000
    rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGXFSZ, {SIG_IGN}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGHUP, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGINT, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGQUIT, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGILL, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGTRAP, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGABRT, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGBUS, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGFPE, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGKILL, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGUSR1, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGSEGV, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGUSR2, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, NULL, {SIG_IGN}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGTERM, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGSTKFLT, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGCHLD, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGCONT, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGSTOP, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGTSTP, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGTTIN, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGTTOU, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGURG, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGXCPU, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGXFSZ, NULL, {SIG_IGN}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGVTALRM, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGPROF, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGWINCH, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGIO, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGPWR, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGSYS, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_2, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_3, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_4, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_5, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_6, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_7, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_8, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_9, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_10, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_11, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_12, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_13, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_14, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_15, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_16, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_17, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_18, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_19, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_20, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_21, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_22, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_23, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_24, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_25, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_26, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_27, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_28, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_29, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_30, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_31, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGRT_32, NULL, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {0x4b8450, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7feb245087d0}, {SIG_DFL}, 8) = 0
    stat("/usr/lib/python25.zip", 0x7fff2cb2d750) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/usr/lib", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=20480, ...}) = 0
    stat("/usr/lib/python25.zip", 0x7fff2cb307d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/usr/lib/python2.5/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=20480, ...}) = 0
    stat("/usr/lib/python2.5/", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=20480, ...}) = 0
    stat("/usr/lib/python2.5/site", 0x7fff2cb30ae0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/site.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/sitemodule.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/site.py", O_RDONLY) = 4
    fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14109, ...}) = 0
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/site.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 5
    fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14300, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24b32000
    read(5, "\263\362\r\n\f\241WKc\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\6\0\0\0@\0\0\0s\f"..., 4096) = 4096
    fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14300, ...}) = 0
    read(5, "\0\0sD\0\0\0Return a set containing a"..., 8192) = 8192
    read(5, "|\2\0i\5\0d\5\0\203\1\0oW\0\1y\21\0|\1\0i\6\0|\2\0\203"..., 4096) = 2012
    read(5, "", 4096)                       = 0
    close(5)                                = 0
    munmap(0x7feb24b32000, 4096)            = 0
    stat("/usr/lib/python2.5/os", 0x7fff2cb2d520) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/os.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/osmodule.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/os.py", O_RDONLY) = 5
    fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=24624, ...}) = 0
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/os.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 6
    fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=24645, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24b32000
    read(6, "\263\362\r\n\376\240WKc\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\36\0\0\0@\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
    fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=24645, ...}) = 0
    read(6, "|\1\0\203\2\0\1d\1\0S(\2\0\0\0s\2\1\0\0makedirs(pa"..., 20480) = 20480
    read(6, "\n\r\n\r\4\t\t\t\f\35\3\r\3\t\n\t\f\35\4\r\1\r\1\17\n\21"..., 4096) = 69
    read(6, "", 4096)                       = 0
    close(6)                                = 0
    munmap(0x7feb24b32000, 4096)            = 0
    mmap(NULL, 266240, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24aa8000
    brk(0x7c1000)                           = 0x7c1000
    stat("/usr/lib/python2.5/posixpath", 0x7fff2cb29f60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/posixpath.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/posixpathmodule.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/posixpath.py", O_RDONLY) = 6
    fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=13777, ...}) = 0
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/posixpath.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 7
    fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=12355, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24aa7000
    read(7, "\263\362\r\n\376\240WKc\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\'\0\0\0@\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
    fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=12355, ...}) = 0
    read(7, "b/python2.5/posixpath.pyR\t\0\0\0\211\0\0"..., 8192) = 8192
    read(7, "\1\6\1\6\1\6\7\t\10\t\t\t\22\t\17\t\r\t\10\t\7\t\7\t\r"..., 4096) = 67
    read(7, "", 4096)                       = 0
    close(7)                                = 0
    munmap(0x7feb24aa7000, 4096)            = 0
    stat("/usr/lib/python2.5/stat", 0x7fff2cb269a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/stat.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/statmodule.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/stat.py", O_RDONLY) = 7
    fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1667, ...}) = 0
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/stat.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 8
    fstat(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2424, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24aa7000
    read(8, "\263\362\r\n\376\240WKc\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\1\0\0\0@\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2424
    fstat(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2424, ...}) = 0
    read(8, "", 4096)                       = 0
    close(8)                                = 0
    munmap(0x7feb24aa7000, 4096)            = 0
    close(7)                                = 0
    close(6)                                = 0
    stat("/usr/lib/python2.5/UserDict", 0x7fff2cb29f60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/UserDict.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/UserDictmodule.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/UserDict.py", O_RDONLY) = 6
    fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5729, ...}) = 0
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/UserDict.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 7
    fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=8772, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24aa7000
    read(7, "\263\362\r\n\376\240WKc\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0\0\0@\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
    fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=8772, ...}) = 0
    read(7, "hon2.5/UserDict.pyR*\0\0\0C\0\0\0s\2\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
    read(7, "Ni\1\0\0\0(\6\0\0\0R\2\0\0\0R\v\0\0\0R7\0\0\0R\6\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 580
    read(7, "", 4096)                       = 0
    close(7)                                = 0
    munmap(0x7feb24aa7000, 4096)            = 0
    close(6)                                = 0
    stat("/usr/lib/python2.5/copy_reg", 0x7fff2cb29f60) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/copy_reg.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/copy_regmodule.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/copy_reg.py", O_RDONLY) = 6
    fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=6729, ...}) = 0
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/copy_reg.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 7
    fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5124, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24aa7000
    read(7, "\263\362\r\n\376\240WKc\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\10\0\0\0@\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 4096
    fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=5124, ...}) = 0
    read(7, " already in use for key %s(\5\0\0\0t"..., 4096) = 1028
    read(7, "", 4096)                       = 0
    close(7)                                = 0
    munmap(0x7feb24aa7000, 4096)            = 0
    stat("/usr/lib/python2.5/types", 0x7fff2cb269a0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/types.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/typesmodule.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/types.py", O_RDONLY) = 7
    fstat(7, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2542, ...}) = 0
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/types.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 8
    fstat(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2708, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24aa7000
    read(8, "\263\362\r\n\376\240WKc\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\23\0\0\0@\0\0\0"..., 4096) = 2708
    fstat(8, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2708, ...}) = 0
    read(8, "", 4096)                       = 0
    close(8)                                = 0
    munmap(0x7feb24aa7000, 4096)            = 0
    close(7)                                = 0
    close(6)                                = 0
    close(5)                                = 0
    stat("/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
    open("/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|0x80000) = 5
    fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISGID|0775, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
    fcntl(5, F_GETFD)                       = 0x1 (flags FD_CLOEXEC)
    getdents(5, /* 2 entries */, 4096)      = 48
    stat("/proc/..", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
    stat("/proc/.", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    getdents(5, /* 0 entries */, 4096)      = 0
    close(5)                                = 0
    stat("/usr/local/lib/site-python", 0x7fff2cb310f0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file
```

... snip ...

```
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/types.py", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/types.pyc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/encodings", 0x7fff2cb2c5e0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/encodings.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/encodingsmodule.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/encodings.py", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/encodings.pyc", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/aliases", 0x7fff2cb2c5d0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/aliases.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/aliasesmodule.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/aliases.py", O_RDONLY) = 5
    fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=14337, ...}) = 0
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/aliases.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 6
    fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9100, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24a61000
    read(6, "\263\362\r\n\0\241WKc\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0sx"..., 4096) = 4096
    fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=9100, ...}) = 0
    read(6, "t\6\0\0\0cp1258t\4\0\0\0001258t\f\0\0\0windows"..., 4096) = 4096
    read(6, "let\25\0\0\0unicodelittleunmarkedt\10\0\0"..., 4096) = 908
    read(6, "", 4096)                       = 0
    close(6)                                = 0
    munmap(0x7feb24a61000, 4096)            = 0
    close(5)                                = 0
    close(4)                                = 0
    stat("/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/utf_8", 0x7fff2cb30860) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/utf_8.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/utf_8module.so", O_RDONLY) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/utf_8.py", O_RDONLY) = 4
    fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1005, ...}) = 0
    open("/usr/lib/python2.5/encodings/utf_8.pyc", O_RDONLY) = 5
    fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1950, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24a61000
    read(5, "\263\362\r\n\0\241WKc\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\4\0\0\0@\0\0\0s\230"..., 4096) = 1950
    fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=1950, ...}) = 0
    read(5, "", 4096)                       = 0
    close(5)                                = 0
    munmap(0x7feb24a61000, 4096)            = 0
    close(4)                                = 0
    ioctl(0, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
    ioctl(1, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
    ioctl(2, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, {B38400 opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
    readlink("test.py", 0x7fff2cb331a0, 4096) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
    getcwd("/root", 4096)                   = 6
    lstat("/root/test.py", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30, ...}) = 0
    ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_TIMEBASE or TCGETS, 0x7fff2cb35130) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)
    fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24a61000
    lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)                   = 0
    read(3, "import os\nos.listdir(\"/tmp\")\n\n", 4096) = 30
    lseek(3, 30, SEEK_SET)                  = 30
    read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
    close(3)                                = 0
    munmap(0x7feb24a61000, 4096)            = 0
    open("/tmp", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|0x80000) = 3
    fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|S_ISVTX|0777, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
    getdents(3, /* 6 entries */, 4096)      = 200
    open("/proc/../cmdline", O_RDONLY)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/proc/redirect.log", 0x7fff2cb31cb0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    stat("/proc/.", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0555, st_size=0, ...}) = 0
    stat("/proc/php_errors.log", 0x7fff2cb31cb0) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
    getdents(3, /* 0 entries */, 4096)      = 0
    close(3)                                = 0
    write(2, "Traceback (most recent call last"..., 35Traceback (most recent call last):
    ) = 35
    open("test.py", O_RDONLY)               = 3
    write(2, "  File \"test.py\", line 2, in <mo"..., 38  File "test.py", line 2, in <module>
    ) = 38
    fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=30, ...}) = 0
    mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7feb24a61000
    read(3, "import os\nos.listdir(\"/tmp\")\n\n", 4096) = 30
    write(2, "    ", 4    )                     = 4
    write(2, "os.listdir(\"/tmp\")\n", 19os.listdir("/tmp")
    )  = 19
    close(3)                                = 0
    munmap(0x7feb24a61000, 4096)            = 0
    write(2, "OSError", 7OSError)                  = 7
    write(2, ": ", 2: )                       = 2
    write(2, "[Errno 2] No such file or direct"..., 43[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp') = 43
    write(2, "\n", 1
    )                       = 1
    rt_sigaction(SIGINT, {SIG_DFL}, {0x4b8450, [], SA_RESTORER, 0x7feb245087d0}, 8) = 0
    exit_group(1)                           = ?
    Process 11879 detached
```

Comment: Do you have read access to "/" ?

Comment: The strangest line in the strace is `stat("/proc/php_errors.log", ...)`.  Why should `os.listdir("/tmp")` try to stat `/proc/php_errors.log`?  And why should there be such a file anyway?

Comment: @kurumi: The call `open("/tmp", ...)` in the strace is successful, so there is at least read access to `/tmp`, but the `os.listdir()` call fails anyway.

Comment: Could you post an `ls -l /tmp` output (or alternatively `ls -l /`, but also substitute the strace by the one for `os.listdir("/")`)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is caused by a rootkit. I'm just looking at the same problem on a Debian (lenny) server I administer. Look at the top of strace:

```
open("/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLY)    = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=22, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 22, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7feb24b32000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libncom.so.4.0.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

libncom is not something that should be on the system. It hides some files including itself and /etc/ld.preload.so.
There is a bug is libncom(?) that causes it to return ENOENT for every readdir, which in turn causes python os.listdir() to fail. Without that I would not have noticed it at all.

As I understand it, the best practice for this kind of thing is to take a forensics copy and reinstall.

Comment: I'd suspect this or related vulnerability has been used: http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2010-4344

Comment: FYI it is easy to detect the presence of this file by just doing less /lib/libncom.so.4.0.1

Answer (score 1):

```
open("/etc/ld.so.preload", O_RDONLY)    = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=22, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 22, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7feb24b32000
close(3)                                = 0
open("/lib/libncom.so.4.0.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

This is caused by a rootkit . the rootkit have some bugs. after affect by this rootkit...u run `find / -name ls` ... then will show you some error like that:

```
find: /: No such file or directory
```

how to fix:

```
rm -rf \`cat /etc/ld.so.preload\` ; > /etc/ld.so.preload ; reboot
```

after reboot... you will find `os.listdir()` work.....